# Replicate category pages to show just sale products

Tags: magento-1.9, module, special-price

In Magento 1.9.2.x I would like to create a custom module that will show all sale items (anything with a current special price) within a different section of the store but retaining the normal category hierarchy/structure and filtered navigation etc.

Example:

Standard category URLs showing non-sale items:

```
/books/
/videos/
/games/
```

New URLs showing only sale items within those same categories:

```
/sale/books/
/sale/videos/
/sale/games/
```

Previously we have done this by creating the "Sale" category and replicating the standard category tree beneath that and assigning products to those categories.

This quickly becomes un-manageable for a large catalogue, and when special prices end it is almost impossible to remember to remove the items from the Sale categories. A previous dev tried scripting the removal of products from sale categories but I don't feel that is the right approach either.

[This guide from Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/more-flexible-approach-for-listing-out-products-on-sale-in-magento/) looks like it will help me achieve most of what I want. The missing part is how I could implement the normal (/) and sale (/sale/) category URL structure.

Any ideas how I may handle this?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a custom module and register 'sale' as its frontname and the category's url_key as a parameter (eg. /sale/category/books) 
i have some hints here for you regarding loading the products. when you want to have all filters available from the layered nav you should load the products via the catalog/layer model...

Namespace/Module/config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <saleproducts>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>{Namespace_Module}</module>
                <frontName>sale</frontName>
            </args>
        </saleproducts>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <saleproducts>
                <file>sale.xml</file>
            </saleproducts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Namespace/Module/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
class Namespace_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout(); 
    }
}
```

in the layout file /design/frontend/base/default/layout/sale.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sale_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sale/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </sale_index_index>
</layout>
```

and a Block in Namespace/Module/Block/Product/List.php :

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
 protected function _getProductCollection()
{

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($this->getRequest()->getCategory(), 'url_key');
        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
        $productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();

        return $productCollection;

}
```